# Updating table issue in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, annotations

I have an ASP.NET MVC model class like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public partial class Customer
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Rates_Comments = new HashSet<Rates_Comments>();
    }

    [Required]
    public double ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Marital_Status { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Range(5000,500000)]
    public double Income { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double Children { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Education { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Occupation { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Home_Owner { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<h2>Update My Account:</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-inline">
    <hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

    <div class="form-group" style="width:380px;">

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Email-User Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-10" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:220px", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                <br />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("First Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-10" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.F_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:220px" } })
                <br />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.F_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Last Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-10" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.L_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:220px" } })
                <br />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.L_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Marital_Status,Gender,Income,Children,Education,Occupation,Home_Owner,Cars,Commute_Distance,Region,Age,Buy,OrderNumber")] Customer customer)
{
        int[] Children = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        ViewBag.OrderNumber = new SelectList(db.Orders, "OrderNumber", "OrderNumber");
        ViewBag.Gender = new SelectList(db.Customers.Select(x => x.Gender).Distinct());
        ViewBag.email = new SelectList(db.Customers.Select(x => x.Email).Distinct());
        ViewBag.fn = new SelectList(db.Customers.Select(x => x.F_Name).Distinct());
        ViewBag.ln = new SelectList(db.Customers.Select(x => x.L_Name).Distinct());
        ViewBag.pas = new SelectList(db.Customers.Select(x => x.Pass).Distinct());
        ViewBag.Marital_Status = new SelectList(db.Customers.Select(x => x.Marital_Status).Distinct());
        ViewBag.Education = new SelectList(db.Customers.Select(x => x.Education).Distinct());
        ViewBag.Occupation = new SelectList(db.Customers.Select(x => x.Occupation).Distinct());
        ViewBag.Home_Owner = new SelectList(db.Customers.Select(x => x.Home_Owner).Distinct());
        ViewBag.Cars = new SelectList(db.Customers.Select(x => x.Cars).Distinct());
        ViewBag.Commute_Distance = new SelectList(db.Customers.Select(x => x.Commute_Distance).Distinct());
        ViewBag.Region = new SelectList(db.Customers.Select(x => x.Region).Distinct());
        ViewBag.Children = new SelectList(Children);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.OrderNumber = new SelectList(db.Orders, "OrderNumber", "OrderNumber", customer.OrderNumber);
        return View(customer);
}
```

My issue that because of the `[Required]` data annotations, I can't update one cell in my table for example, user have to access his account to edit it if he needs to, so he may only edit one filed, not all of it.

And due registration issue, all filed are required, so how to overcome this one?